# ¿Cómo puedo detectar fugas de memoria en mi programa en C utilizando DEV C++?

Tags: c, dev-c++

Utilizo Dev C++ versión 5.11 y sistema operativo Windows 8.1, mi pregunta es para un programa que desarrollo en C ¿cómo puedo verificar que el programa esté libre de memory leaks o fugas de memorias?. 
Gracias

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**NOTA**

En los comentarios a la respuesta, @JacoboCórdova indica que son necesarias algunas modificaciones para que funcione.

Supongo que son debidas a los diferentes compiladores usados.

**Incluyo** dicha modificación, convenientemente marcada en `leaks.c`. En caso de problemas, ELIMINAR dicho cambio.

**FIN DE NOTA**

Hay una forma relativamente simple:

Tienes que crear 2 archivos adicionales a tu proyecto: uno de cabecera

```
// leaks.h

#ifndef LEAKS_H
#define LEAKS_H

#include <stddef.h>

// ESTE INCLUDE NO DEBERÍA DE SER NECESARIO.
#include "leaks.c"
// SI HAY PROBLEMAS, ELIMINARLO.

#define malloc( S ) ( my_malloc( (S) ) )
#define calloc( C, S ) ( my_calloc( (C), (S) ) )
#define free( P ) ( my_free( (P) ) )

void *my_malloc( size_t );
void *my_calloc( size_t, size_t );
void my_free( void * );

#endif
```

y otro con algo de código. Observa que, en dicho archivo, **no incluimos** el anterior `leaks.h`:

```
// leaks.c

#include <stdlib.h>

static size_t leaks = 0;

void *my_malloc( size_t s ) {
  ++leaks;
  return malloc( s );
}

void *my_calloc( size_t n, size_t s ) {
  ++leaks;
  return calloc( n, s );
}

void my_free( void *p ) {
  --leaks;
  free( p );
}

size_t leaks_count( void ) {
  return leaks;
}
```

Ahora, para usar la *nueva* característica, has de incluir `"leaks.h"` **al principio de todos los archivos `.c` que quieras comprobar**. Concretamente, ha de ser el último `#include ""` que tengas.

Y una última modificación. En el lugar en el que quieras saber como llevas el número de *fugas*, por ejemplo en el `main.c`:

```
// main.c

#include <stdio.h>

#include "leaks.h"
// ESTO ES MUY IMPORTANTE
// LO COLOCAMOS FUERA DE CUALQUIER FUNCIÓN.
// PREFERIBLEMENTE, DESPUES DE LOS #include
size_t leaks_count( void );

int main( void ) {
  char *tmp = malloc( 100 );

  free( tmp );

  printf( "Bloques sin liberar: %zu\n", leaks_count( ) );
  // para Windows
  //printf( "Bloques sin liberar: %Iu\n", leaks_count( ) );
  return 0;
}
```

Como ves, la idea es *reemplazar* las llamadas a funciones normales por llamadas a nuestras funciones de reemplazo, y hacer allí lo que tengamos que hacer. No es ninguna maravilla, pero puede darnos una idea de como llevamos las fugas de memoria.

Fíjate que **no** *reemplazamos* `realloc( )`. Lo dejo como *entretenimiento* ;-)

**NOTA**

Esta implementación propuesta solo **cuenta el número de veces que llamamos a `malloc( )` y `free( )` en nuestros archivos fuente**. Eso implica que **no es, ni mucho menos, un control exhaustivo** de lo que hacemos.

Para obtener datos mas **exactos**, tenemos varias opciones:

1. Utilizar alguna de las múltiples herramientas disponibles.
2. Reemplazar **por completo** las funciones del sistema que nos interesen. Eso es mas complejo, pero **perfectamente posible**, y es lo que hacen esas herramientas.
3. Extender nuestras funciones `my_malloc( )`, `my_calloc( )`, ...
   Ahora mismo, apenas hacemos nada. **Pero** nada nos impide aumentar nuestra funcionalidad, devolviendo cosas distintas, contando los *bytes* exactos que estamos usando, contemplar `realloc( )`, crear nodos de listas enlazadas de los bloques, incluir incluso el nombre del archivo exacto en el que realizamos la reserva (usando `__FILE__`), ...

**EDITO**

Es **muy importante** que comprendamos una cosa: **es posible tener fugas de memoria aunque hagamos los `alloc( )` y `free( )` correctos**.

Ya entramos de lleno en cosas de *bajo nivel*, pero creo que es importante saberlo.

Las funciones de reserva/liberación de memoria **no son milagrosas**; son simples funciones, **y pueden añadir cosas a lo que nosostros pedimos**.

La mayoría, de hecho, añaden cosas **antes de la dirección que nos devuelven**.

Con esto, quiero decir que, si accedemos **de forma errónea** a punteros devueltos por `malloc( )` y similares, podemos corromper los datos internos del sistema de memoria. Como consecuencia, podemos hacer un uso correcto de dichas funciones, y, aún así, ir dejando *huecos* en la memoria que **no se podrán recuperar** (hasta que cerremos el programa).

Un pequeño ejemplo:

```
struct mydata_s {
  int algo;
  float otro_algo;
  struct mydata_s *mas_de_algo;
} *ptr;


ptr = (struct mydata_s *)malloc( sizeof( struct mydata_s ) );

( ptr - 1 )->algo = 0;

free( ptr );
```

El código anterior **accede a una zona justo antes de lo que nos devolvió `malloc( )`**.

Ahí, pueden pasar varias cosas:

1. No pasa nada (no veas que suerte).
2. Corrompemos **nuestros propios datos** de un `malloc( )` anterior.
3. Error del sistema operativo (difícil en el ejemplo, pero posible).
4. Error al llamar a `free( )` (el sistema de gestión se dio cuenta).
5. **Corrupción** del sistema de gestión de memoria.

En este último punto, puede pasar, literalmente, **de todo**. Entre otras cosas, podemos dejar un hueco **enorme** en la memoria que **nunca podremos usar**.

C es famoso y temido por la facilidad que ofrece para manipular *a nuestro antojo* la memoria. Ahí tenemos un posible motivo para lo segundo. **¡ Mucho cuidado con lo que hacemos con nuestros punteros !**

Comment: Hola @trauma Gracias por responder, he compilado el codigo pero me arroja un error en el archivo de cabecera `leaks.h ` el cual es este `[Error] expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '(' token `segun lo que pude vver en una busqueda en google parece algo relacionado con los parentesis, pero allí veo todo bien. el error lo marca cuatro veces, uno por (S) (C) (S) y (P) de los `#define malloc( S ) ( my_malloc( (S) ) )
#define calloc( C, S ) ( my_calloc(  (C),  (S) ) )
#define free( P ) ( my_free( (P) ) ) ` ¿que podría ser? Gracias

Comment: @JacoboCórdova ¡¡¡ Ahhhggg !!! ¡¡¡ **Muy grave error por mi parte** !!! Corregido. He cambiado un poco las *instrucciones de uso*, y modificado el contenido de `my_malloc( )`. ¡ A ver si voy despabilando !

Comment: Listo, muchas gracias por esta solución; dos cosas, para lograr que corriera tuve que agreagar al archivo `leaks.h` un `#include "leaks.c" `  y como trabajo con windows el formato de impresión del size_t tuvo que ser así `printf( "Bloques sin liberar: %Iu\n", leaks_count( ) ); ` Del resto creo que la mejora posible, podría que ser con una pila que almacene las direcciones de memoria asignadas, para luego ser rectificadas a medida que se vayan liberando.

Comment: @JacoboCórdova que raro lo de incluir `leaks.c` en el `.h`. El ejemplo que pongo al final, a mi me compiló sin problemas tal y como lo puse.

Comment: Lo del `printf( )` ... pues lo mismo. Según el estándar, lo puse bien. Y en mi Linux + gcc, funciona bien.

Comment: @Trauma Creo que ese `#include` debe ir despues de los prototipos de función.

Comment: @NaCl lo ha puesto el OP; ha editado él mismo la respuesta, para evitar malentendidos :-) Es lo que a él le ha funcionado.

Comment: Gracias @Trauma por la amabilidad, lo cierto es que colocando el include después de la definición de los prototipos el programa cierra inesperadamente. Si no lo incluyo el programa tambien cierra inesperadamente. e ambos casos al abrir dice que ha detectado un problema y debe cerrarse.

Comment: @JacoboCórdova sinceramente, **ni idea**. No uso Windows, así que no puedo probar con `Dev C++` para orientarte mas. Usando `gcc` en Linux, el `main.c` que te he puesto funciona perfecto (quitando el `#include "leaks.c"`que indicaste en `leaks.h`).  Marcala como `no resuelta`, a ver si obtienes mas respuestas. O crea una pregunta nueva, indicando los pasos exactos que estas haciendo, el IDE, los errores que obtienes, ... en fín, todo lo que se te ocurra. A ver si alguien nos puede orientar a los dos, porque yo también estoy intrigado :-?

Comment: Pues para mi esta mas que resuelta, solo coloque los comentarios, para dejar claro todo lo que me ocurrió, pero la solución es correcta para mi, y estoy muy agradecido. :) como dije, colocando esas lineas no tuve errores, pero como @NaCl sugirio un cambio en la posicion del include, quise dejar constancia de que intente hacerlo de esa manera tambien. me parece ademas que en tu edicion esta muy claro todo para cualquiera que quiera hacer algo similar y me parece que esta bien completa. Saludos cordiales